# How to know if a kernel code is atomic or not?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, atomic

I am writing a kernel module where I implement some functions that are going to be used from another modules I have modified. When testing the system crashes. I get a "scheduling while atomic" error.

After debugging, I realized that the system crashes when a `atomic_set()` is called. It means that I am calling an atomic function from a non-atomic function? can't I use atomic_set() in this case? What should I use instead?

Also, as I said, I modified some original kernel files for calling my function. How could I know if where I am working is atomic code or not?

**EDIT: Adding the actual code**

In [net/netfilter/ipvs/ip_vs_core.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=net/netfilter/ipvs/ip_vs_core.c;h=a54b018c6eea72fc122aa47c6f66de76676c1fa1;hb=HEAD) line 451, I call my function:

```
my_callback(svc, skb);
```

Then, in another file I have:

```
int my_callback(struct ip_vs_service *svc, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
        int swto;

        printk(KERN_INFO "callback called \n");

        swto = swtoing(svc);
        return swto;
}
```

My `swtoing()` function is a bit long, but I had debugged a lot, and have figured out that the system does not crash if I comment a line within `swtoing()` with a `atomic_set()`...

Any help?

**EDIT 2: More info**

I realized that the kernel modules I am modifying are FULL of `spin_locks` and stuff like that... So I think (forgive me if I am wrong) that I must do something in the functions that I am creating, in order to keep the locking/atomic stuff... but I don't know what :(

Comment: Likely it means you're in an atomic context (e.g. holding spinlocks or in an irq handler), and you called some function that sleeps.

Comment: Can you please provide some context: is your own code crashing? can you show the relevant modifications? Also, read http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.5/Documentation/atomic_ops.txt

Comment: @nos and how do I know I am in "atomic context"? And If so, what should I use instead of atomic_set()?

Comment: It sounds very unlikely this is caused by atomic_set()

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I added some code, hope it helps

Comment: @nos I updated the question with some additional info

Comment: @nos Thank you for the insight. I am writing a driver and a lot of callback state "this is an atomic callback" which I had no idea what that meant. No sleeping... thus, things like synchronize_rcu( ) are a no go... good to know

Answer (score 1):

You can use [in_atomic](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.5/include/linux/hardirq.h#L109) macro but is has some restrictions. See the comment.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have edited the question to add more info

Comment: More information on the (don't-)use of `in_atomic` macro: https://lwn.net/Articles/274695/